# Grabbing first number in string after some keyword occurrence in C++ (Arduino)

Tags: string, arduino, serial-port, microcontroller, arduino-c++

I have a string coming from PC through serial to a microcontroller (Arduino), e.g.:

```
"HDD: 55 - CPU: 12.6 - Weather: Cloudy [...] $";
```

by this function I found:

```
String inputStringPC = "";
boolean stringCompletePC = false;

void serialEvent() {
  while (Serial.available()) {
    char inChar = (char)Serial.read();

    inputStringPC += inChar;

    if (inChar == '$') // end marker of the string 
    {
      stringCompletePC = true;
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to extract the **first number** of it after the word *HDD*, *CPU* and also get the **string** after *Weather* (ie "cloudy"); my thinking is something like that:

```
   int HDD = <function that does that>(Keyword HDD);

   double CPU = <function that does that>(Keyword CPU);

   char Weather[] = <function that does that>(Keyword Weather);
```

> What is the right function to do that?

I looked into inputStringSerial.indexOf("HDD") but I am still a learner to properly understand what it does and don't know if theres a better function.

*My approach yielded some syntax errors and confused me with the difference in usage between "String inputStringSerial" (class?) and "char inputStringSerial[]" (variable?). When I do 'string inputStringSerial = "";' PlatformIO complains that "string" is undefined.*  Any help to understand its usage here is greatly appreciated.

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: This is not C. There is no `class` in C language.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe a misinterpretation by VS Code? I am using PlatformIO.

Comment: @nolimits Not a misinterpretation. Arduino is C++ not C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The String class provides member functions to search and copy the contents of the String. That class and all its member functions are documented in the Arduino Reference:
https://www.arduino.cc/reference/tr/language/variables/data-types/stringobject/

The other way a list of characters can be represented is a char array, confusingly also called a string or cstring. The functions to search and copy the contents of a char array are documented at
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/

Here is a simple Sketch that copies and prints the value of the Weather field using a String object. Use this same pattern - with different head and terminator values - to copy the string values of the other fields.

Once you have the string values of HDD and CPU, you'll need to call functions to convert those string values into int and float values. See the String member functions toInt() and toFloat() at
https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/string/functions/toint/
or the char array functions atoi() and atof() at
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/?kw=atoi

```
String inputStringPC = "HDD: 55 - CPU: 12.6 - Weather: Cloudy [...] $";

const char headWeather[] = "Weather: "; // the prefix of the weather value
const char dashTerminator[] = " -";     // one possible suffix of a value
const char dollarTerminator[] = " $";   // the other possible suffix of a value

void setup() {
  int firstIndex;     // index into inputStringPC of the first char of the value
  int lastIndex;      // index just past the last character of the value
  Serial.begin(9600);

  // find the Weather field and copy its string value.
  // Use similar code to copy the values of the other fields.

  // NOTE: This code contains no error checking for unexpected input values.

  firstIndex = inputStringPC.indexOf(headWeather);
  firstIndex += strlen(headWeather); // firstIndex is now the index of the char just past the head.

  lastIndex = inputStringPC.indexOf(dollarTerminator, firstIndex);

  String value = inputStringPC.substring(firstIndex, lastIndex);

  Serial.print("Weather value = '");
  Serial.print(value);
  Serial.println("'");
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

When run on an Arduio Uno, this Sketch produces:

```
Weather value = 'Cloudy [...]'
```

Comment: I probably should have used headWeather.length() instead of strlen(headWeather), to consistently use String functions instead of cstring functions.

Comment: Thanks heaps. My understanding is that the 'lastIndex' uses the unique $ terminator. Its not clear to me how to use it for the the - terminator because it occurs multiple times. Any clue?

Comment: The second parameter of .indexOf() tells where to start the search from, so the search for the terminator finds the first occurrence of the terminator after the header you found. So for example the search for the Weather terminator finds the first occurrence of " $" after the "Weather: " header. It ignores earlier occurrences of the terminator in inputStringPC.

Comment: Ah! So its relative and I can set lastIndex = inputStringPC.indexOf(hyphenTerminator, inputStringPC.indexOf("HDD: ")) ?

Comment: Yes. I also like to check the return value of each call to .indexOf() to make sure it found the string I expected (that is, that indexOf(...) >= 0)